# Firebase events not being logged

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to integrate Firebase analytics into an Android app and am having trouble logging events. Here is the code I've used:

```
firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE , value);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType);

firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

I have enabled logging to Logcat and the only FA logs I see are:

App measurement is starting up, version: 10084
Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used

Firebase console hasn't reported any events even after multiple days.
I'm a bit stumped, does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Where did you implement that code? Is it in a click of a button?

Comment: When a dialog is opened

Comment: Can you post all FA tagged logcat messages. Firebase will log more then just the message you posted.

Comment: @johnjohnsonson Have you made sure that the google-services json file on the client is using the same project id and number as on your Firebase console. In short - you must be using the same json file that the console provides.